# Чем является «знаешь [союзное слово]» в предложении?

Tags: смысл, части-речи, частица

Все мы знаем, что в подобных сочетаниях запятая не ставится:

1. Я это **знаешь как** сделал?
2. Он **знаешь когда** пришел?
3. Нам **знаешь что** для этого пригодилось?

Но меня интересует, какую роль выделенные слова играют? И какой частью речи они являются? Они очень похожи на частицу.

Answer (score 0):

*Я это ***знаешь*** как сделал?*

*Он ***знаешь*** когда пришел?*

*Нам ***знаешь*** что для этого пригодилось?*

Исходные предложения:  **Знаешь, как** я это  сделал?  **Знаешь,  когда** он пришел? **Знаешь, что**  для нам этого пригодилось?

Далее **инверсия**, ослабление значение глагола и переход **в частицу**, отсутствие пауз и запятых в **разговорном** стиле.

**[Розенталь](http://old-rozental.ru/paragraph.php?file=pt_25.htm#ppp_8)**

В приведенных примерах лексическое значение слов видишь, знаешь и т. п. **ослаблено**, поскольку они оказались **внутри предложения**, которое по смыслу должно было бы от них зависеть; ср.: Знаешь, что нам за это будет?; Знаете, что я нашёл в углу?; Видишь, что делает бабка Варвара? [См. § 33, п. 3.]

**[Розенталь](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=137#pp137)**

**Пункт 3.** Если главная часть сложноподчиненного предложения находится внутри придаточной **(в разговорном стиле речи)**, то запятая обычно ставится только после главной части (а перед ней не ставится); Не выделяются запятыми слова ***видишь, знаешь*** и т. п. в вопросительно-восклицательных предложениях типа: А он **знаешь** какой хороший!; А он **видишь** что делает?т См. [§ 25, п. 8.](http://old-rozental.ru/paragraph.php?file=pt_25.htm#ppp_8)